# How Can I Select an ItemTemplate Based on a Value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a collection of objects that I'm showing in an `ItemsControl` and depending on a value within each object I want to show a different ItemTemplate/DataTemplate. I know you can do this with different object types, but can it be done based on a value?

```
public class MyItem {
    public int MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
```

---

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">

<!--If MyValue == 1-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

<!--If MyValue == 2-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

<!--If MyValue == 3-->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ComboBox/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, if you can do it just with Style triggers (as in Neil B’s answer), do. If your value is more complicated you may need another option...

When you have complex values to switch templates on you can use a `DataTemplateSelector`. It's a bit more overhead/complication but opens up your options.

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null && item is MyItem myItem)
        {
            switch (myItem.MyValue)
            {
                case 1:
                    return element.FindResource("TextBoxResource") as DataTemplate;
                case 2:
                    return element.FindResource("CheckBoxResource") as DataTemplate;
                case 3:
                    return element.FindResource("ComboBoxResource") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null; // or provide a default template
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML:

```
<App.Resources>
    <!-- these resources can be in any context such as app, window, or user control, they just need to be in scope -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxResource">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxResource">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxResource">
        <Grid>
            <ComboBox/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myDataTemplateSelector"/>
</App.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myDataTemplateSelector}">
</ItemsControl>
```

The data template selector is then explicitly selecting the DataTemplate to provide to the ItemsControl, and the ItemTemplateSelector property of ItemsControl is mutually exclusive with the ItemTemplate property (you can't set both at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you would use triggers for that.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <!--default template-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBox/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <CheckBox/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyValue}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBox/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but MyValue is a child of MyItems, but it thinks its a child of MyItems' parent context.. How can I set MyValue relative to MyItems?

Comment: The trigger as I've show can't access the item properties. See the other answer for an example of using a DataTemplateSelector.